# Embed Streams onto website

Tags: embed, jwplayer, rtmp, flowplayer

Good-day, I have these streams http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9987/udp/239.100.0.105:1234 which i can play through VLC and Sm Player. Can i embed these streams onto a website using these URL's through something like JWPlayer or Flow player?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JWPlayer.
Add JW Player library to your page:

```
​<script src="//p.jwpcdn.com/6/9/jwplayer.js" ></script>
```

And the script

```
<div id=myElement></div>
<script>
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            file: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9987/udp/239.100.0.105:1234",
            image: "myVideo.jpg", //only if you have image
            height: 360,
            width: 640
        });
</script>
```

HLS in Flash is only supported in the JW6 Premium and Ads editions, so if your stream is HLS you'll to buy licence (rtmp works in free edition)

If you're looking for free player which support HLS you can use [Video-JS](http://videojs.com) with this plugin: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls

exapmle: http://ecmendenhall.github.io/hls-aac.html

Edit 1:

```
<div id=myElement></div>
<script>
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            file: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9987/udp/239.100.0.105:1234",
            image: "myVideo.jpg", //only if you have image
            height: 360,
            width: 640,
            primary:;flash',
            type:'hls'
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ben, I did get my rtmp links streaming using this script, But the http links dont work.. For the video-js, would i use the same script?

Comment: could you provide link where you run this?

Comment: paste your link here and press play, does your link work?
http://www.jwplayer.com/wizard/

Comment: ok, thank you, added stream in there and got now viewable sources

Comment: sorry, meant no playable sources found when using the jwplayer wizard. but does work when using rtmp links

Comment: I think there is problem with crossdomain.xml, see my edit.Your link is hls and not rtmp, you need premium version of JWPLayer

Comment: Thanks tried your edited script, but still shows no playable sources found.

Comment: Are you sure your stream is not HLS?

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are embedding the player on your site and having issues.

Comment: http://fanslounge.tv/live/stream/foxsports3.php   - I've added one here so you can check,